# Redirect to other address if main address is unavailable in Ocelot Gateway API

Tags: asp.net, gateway, ocelot

I'd like to use Ocelot Gateway Api to connect to server, but if server is unavailable (e.g. PC is offline), I want to use local service instead.
For example, if first `localhost:7001` failed, use `localhost:7002`.

```
{
    "Routes": [
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/catalog",
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 7001
                },
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 7002
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/catalog-api"
        }
    ],
    "GlobalConfiguration": {
            "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:7000"
    }
}
```

Is such thing even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. Ocelot supports load-balancing natively. In fact, by specifying multiple downstream paths, Ocelot will automatically load balance to the service which has the fewest number of active connections.

To have more control over the load-balancer functionality, you can specify the loadBalancerType property:

```
{
    "Routes": [
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/catalog",
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "LoadBalancerOptions": {
                "Type": "<<load balancer type here>>"
            },
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 7001
                },
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 7002
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/catalog-api"
        }
    ]
}
```

From the docs:

> The type of load balancer available are:
>
> - LeastConnection - tracks which services are dealing with requests and    sends new requests to service with least existing requests. The
>   algorythm state is not distributed across a cluster of Ocelot’s.
> - RoundRobin - loops through available services and sends requests. The    algorythm state is not distributed across a cluster of
>   Ocelot’s.
> - NoLoadBalancer - takes the first available service from config or    service discovery.
> - CookieStickySessions - uses a cookie to stick all requests to a    specific server

From this is seems like the one you want is paradoxically called "NoLoadBalancer".

Reference: https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/loadbalancer.html

Comment: Hello. Thanks for Your answer. *NoLoadBalancer* didn't match my requirements, but I create my own *CustomLoadBalancer*. Thank You for showing me the path!